# Literature on interferometry

Tags: optics, atomic-physics, resource-recommendations, interferometry

I am looking for a good book/notes etc. about interferometry. I need detailed information about optical as well as atom interferometers with strong emphasis on quantum version for high precision measurements.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cronin, Schmiedmayer & Pritchard, [*Optics and Interferometry with Atoms and Molecules*](http://hdl.handle.net/1721.1/52372), Rev. Mod. Phy. 81, 1051 (2009), is a long and detailed paper about atom interferometry.

The abstract says: "...In this review the basic tools for coherent atom optics are described including diffraction by nanostructures and laser light, three-grating interferometers, and double wells on atom chips. Scientific advances in a broad range of fields that have resulted from the application of atom interferometers are reviewed. These are grouped in three categories: (i) fundamental quantum science, (ii) precision metrology, and (iii) atomic and molecular physics. Although some experiments with Bose-Einstein condensates are included, the focus of the review is on linear matter wave optics, i.e., phenomena where each single atom interferes with itself."

The link should take you to an abstract page where you can download a PDF of the paper, courtesy of MIT Open Access Papers.

Here are some papers that specifically deal with Bose-Einstein condensates (quantum metrology):

(1)  [*Quantum Metrology with Bose-Einstein Condensates*](https://resolver.caltech.edu/CaltechAUTHORS:20100510-121135555), according to the abstract, shows how "...a generalized quantum metrology protocol can be implemented in a two-mode Bose-Einstein condensate"

(2)  This paper by Christian Gross, [*Spin squeezing, entanglement and quantum metrology with Bose-Einstein condensates*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.5359), concentrates on squeezed states, entangled states which allow interferometric sensors to overcome noise.

(3)  [*Quantum Metrology with Bose-Einstein Condensates*](http://etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/1690/) is a PhD thesis submitted by Jessica Cooper and accepted by the University of Leeds.  The abstract says "...we propose experimentally accessible schemes to make quantum-limited measurements, in particular rotation measurements using Bose-Einstein condensates, that are robust to (particle) losses.

(4)  [*Quantum Metrology: Dynamics vs. Entanglement*](http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.2180) is by the same authors as the first paper listed above.  The authors devise a protocol that doesn't generate any entanglement among the constituents, and they propose how it can be implemented in a two-component Bose-Einstein condensate.  This appears to be a predecessor of the first paper.